# One Event Handler for multiple JButtons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, java-8, eventhandler

I want to add an EventHandler for multiple JButtons in Java. I use a JButton array `JButton[] buttons = new JButton[120]`. I used this solution

```
        for (int i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
```

but i think the above code is bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a custom `ActionListener`:

```
CustomActionListener listener = new CustomActionListener();

for (int i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
   buttons[i].addActionListener(listener);
}

class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // Handle click on buttons
         // Use e.getSource() to get the trigger button
         JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
     }
}
```

Comment: i followed your solution but inside `actionPerformed`, the command
`e.getSource().setText("OK"` throws an error.

Comment: what error do you get ? (Are you casting `e.getSource()` to a `JButton` before calling `.setText()` ?)

Comment: i implement this `class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
     btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
     btn.setText("OK");
    }
}`. But i still think this code is dirty.

Comment: thanks dude. I start learning java 2 weeks ago and i'm still a newbie.